# Does rooting a SONY Xperia Z2 remove SONY specific features?

Tags: rooting, unrooting, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-z2

Dear Android Enthusiasts,

I'd like to root my new SONY Xperia Z2, but feeling a bit unsure about that I may loose SONY specific features. I'm new to Android (switched from iOS) and don't know how deep the SONY Android UI/Skin is integrated in the system. So I'm talking about noice-cancelling headphones, camera app, Xperia Lounge, ... Am I able to install and use these apps after routing?

In addition I got some other questions dedicated to this topic:

- As if rooting does not fulfill my expectations, can I reliably restore a backup somehow without loosing any data/settings/...?
- Am I right that rooting a device removes its guarantee? (And is there a way around?)
- Is there a good website containing instructions about rooting and downloading sources? (deliberately objective question)
- Am I able to install a pure/vanilla/stock android os on my device?

I know that I may find answers to my questions somewhere in the internet (I did search A LOT), but I experienced it's very hard to find reliable answers about the specific device "SONY Xperia Z2".

Comment: It's hard to find answers specific to your device because nothing about the question is specific to your device. Rooting is rooting, whatever device you have.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for clarifying this! I got confused about it when I looked at [Anrdoid Central - Rooting your Android](http://www.androidcentral.com/root) because it says "Not rooted yet, stay tuned!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, if you root your Z2 by unlocking the bootloader via Sony's official method, it will permanently blow away the phone's DRM keys. If you root your Z2 via a non-Sony-sanctioned exploit, you can back up the partition with the DRM keys first & can theoretically restore it at some later time (no hard guarantees, but at least it's a possibility instead of eliminated forever as an option).

I know a recent Sony update disabled the exploit that was popular for several months earlier in 2014, but it's possible that there's a new one now.

To wit: it's to your advantage to root the phone via unauthorized exploit, then back up the hidden partition with DRM keys so you can restore it to stock at some later point in time if desired and "have your cake & eat it too" (or if you prefer, avoid burning the bridge behind you).

If you use Sony's official method, you will PERMANENTLY lose any functionality that requires the DRM keys, and Sony won't allow you to get it back, regenerate the keys, or otherwise undo it.

On a related note, the Z3 goes a step further than the Z2, and stores driver libraries used by the camera in protected storage that gets disabled by unlocking as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rooting itself did not remove any apps or functionality from your phone. It simply "opens" our operating system so any app can get full control over it. Most of the sony apps are available on the Google play store.

You do not loose any settings or apps (but sure, make a backup before).
Losing guarantee depends of the developer, as far as i remember sony official publish rooting manuals for some phones. But on the most phones (e.g. Samsung) you will lose your guarantee.

You where able to install a vanilla system, but this will remove the sony functions.

Comment: I just want to know on which device by Sony did you test your theory? The other answer (accepted) contradicts with your answer or the otherwise.

Comment: Which theory did you mean? Here are some guides from sony: http://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Android-development/GUIDE-How-to-Root-Xperia-Smartphones-2011-and-2012-Xperias/td-p/287857 http://developer.sonymobile.com/unlockbootloader/

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question, Rooting Xperia Z2 wont remove any SONY features. 
But if you unlock your bootloader it will remove DRM Keys hence losing SONY features like X-Reality, Camera features etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you love X reality, Sony Cam, Advanced Sony UI don't go with rooting, as far as your data concerned there will be no harm.

If needed to roll back you will get your all featured back.